# Flutter_web, RawKeyboardListener not firing onKey event on hosted page (firebase)

Tags: flutter-web

RawKeyboardListener's onKey event is not firing when my web app is hosted on firebase. The onKey event does fire when I host on localhost. Does anyone know why there is a difference in behavior for rawkeyboardlistener between localhost and firebase hosting?

```
child: RawKeyboardListener(
                  focusNode: _keyboardListenerNode,
                  onKey: () {print("rawkeyboardlistener onkey fired");},
                  child: Form(
                      key: _formKey,
                      onChanged: () {
                        print("Form on changed called");
                      },
                      child: TextFormField(
                        autofocus: true,
                        focusNode: _textNode,
                        controller: _controller,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: InputBorder.none,
                          labelText: widget._hintText,
                          suffix: IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.cancel),
                            onPressed: () {},
                          ),
                        ),
                        onSaved: (val) {
                          setState(() {
                            scannedBarcode = val;
                          });
                        },
                      )))
```